# openni not working

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear all,

So, I finally dared to give **Hydro** a spin and installed it on a **fresh Ubuntu 12.04** 64bit machine. (The machine's only purpose in this life is to run ROS, so all I did was to install Ubuntu 12.04 and its latest updates right before installing ROS Hydro).

The thing is that when I **plug a Microsoft Kinect** and execute *roslaunch openni_launch openni.launch* everything is **OK**. But, when I **plug a PrimeSense RD1.08 or PrimeSense RD1.09** it does **not detect** them::

```
[ INFO] [1390375625.910692278]: No matching device found.... waiting for devices. Reason: openni_wrapper::OpenNIDevice::OpenNIDevice(xn::Context&, const xn::NodeInfo&, const xn::NodeInfo&, const xn::NodeInfo&, const xn::NodeInfo&) @ /tmp/buildd/ros-hydro-openni-camera-1.9.2-0precise-20140117-2223/src/openni_device.cpp @ 61 : creating depth generator failed. Reason: USB interface is not supported!
```

More over, when I **plug an ASUS Xtion Pro**, the thing just **blows up**:

```
martin@martin-U24E:~$ roslaunch openni_launch openni.launch 
... 
process[camera/depth_registered_rectify_depth-14]: started with pid [7090]
process[camera/points_xyzrgb_hw_registered-15]: started with pid [7104]
[ INFO] [1390375812.746335307]: Number devices connected: 1
process[camera/disparity_depth-16]: started with pid [7119]
process[camera/disparity_registered_sw-17]: started with pid [7133]
[FATAL] [1390375812.838870747]: Service call failed!
[FATAL] [1390375812.839177731]: Service call failed!
[FATAL] [1390375812.839430812]: Service call failed!
[FATAL] [1390375812.839533404]: Service call failed!
[FATAL] [1390375812.840017362]: Service call failed!
[FATAL] [1390375812.840183592]: Service call failed!
[FATAL] [1390375812.840222229]: Service call failed!
[FATAL] [1390375812.846948463]: Service call failed!
[FATAL] [1390375812.847145521]: Service call failed!
[FATAL] [1390375812.849545313]: Service call failed!
[FATAL] [1390375812.850908795]: Service call failed!
[camera/camera_nodelet_manager-2] process has died [pid 6894, exit code -11, cmd /opt/ros/hydro/lib/nodelet/nodelet manager __name:=camera_nodelet_manager __log:=/home/martin/.ros/log/06ead13e-8337-11e3-a3f7-c860003ebb31/camera-camera_nodelet_manager-2.log].
log file: /home/martin/.ros/log/06ead13e-8337-11e3-a3f7-c860003ebb31/camera-camera_nodelet_manager-2*.log
process[camera/disparity_registered_hw-18]: started with pid [7148]
process[camera_base_link-19]: started with pid [7162]
process[camera_base_link1-20]: started with pid [7195]
process[camera_base_link2-21]: started with pid [7206]
[camera/rectify_mono-5] process has died [pid 6952, exit code 255, cmd /opt/ros/hydro/lib/nodelet/nodelet load image_proc/rectify camera_nodelet_manager --no-bond image_mono:=rgb/image_mono image_rect:=rgb/image_rect_mono __name:=rectify_mono __log:=/home/martin/.ros/log/06ead13e-8337-11e3-a3f7-c860003ebb31/camera-rectify_mono-5.log].
log file: /home/martin/.ros/log/06ead13e-8337-11e3-a3f7-c860003ebb31/camera-rectify_mono-5*.log
[camera/rectify_color-6] process has died [pid 6970, exit code 255, cmd /opt/ros/hydro/lib/nodelet/nodelet load image_proc/rectify camera_nodelet_manager --no-bond image_mono:=rgb/image_color image_rect:=rgb/image_rect_color __name:=rectify_color __log:=/home/martin/.ros/log/06ead13e-8337-11e3-a3f7-c860003ebb31/camera-rectify_color-6.log].
log file: /home/martin/.ros/log/06ead13e-8337-11e3-a3f7-c860003ebb31/camera-rectify_color-6*.log
[camera/rectify_ir-7] process has died [pid 6984, exit code 255, cmd /opt/ros/hydro/lib/nodelet/nodelet load image_proc/rectify camera_nodelet_manager --no-bond image_mono:=ir/image_raw image_rect:=ir/image_rect_ir __name:=rectify_ir __log:=/home/martin/.ros/log/06ead13e-8337-11e3-a3f7-c860003ebb31/camera-rectify_ir-7.log].
log file: /home/martin/.ros/log/06ead13e-8337-11e3-a3f7-c860003ebb31/camera-rectify_ir-7*.log
[camera/register_depth_rgb-12] process has died [pid 7060, exit code 255, cmd /opt/ros/hydro/lib/nodelet/nodelet load depth_image_proc/register camera_nodelet_manager --no-bond rgb/camera_info:=rgb/camera_info depth/camera_info:=depth/camera_info depth/image_rect:=depth/image_rect_raw depth_registered/image_rect:=depth_registered/sw_registered/image_rect_raw __name:=register_depth_rgb __log:=/home/martin/.ros/log/06ead13e-8337-11e3-a3f7-c860003ebb31/camera-register_depth_rgb-12.log].
log file: /home/martin/.ros/log/06ead13e-8337-11e3-a3f7-c860003ebb31/camera-register_depth_rgb-12*.log
process[camera_base_link3-22]: started with pid [7217]
[camera/depth_metric-10] process has died [pid 7030, exit code 255, cmd /opt/ros/hydro/lib/nodelet/nodelet load depth_image_proc/convert_metric camera_nodelet_manager --no-bond image_raw:=depth/image_raw image:=depth/image __name:=depth_metric __log:=/home/martin/.ros/log/06ead13e-8337-11e3-a3f7-c860003ebb31/camera-depth_metric-10.log].
log file: /home/martin/.ros/log/06ead13e-8337-11e3-a3f7-c860003ebb31/camera-depth_metric-10*.log
[camera/depth_points-11] process has died [pid 7044, exit code 255, cmd /opt/ros/hydro/lib/nodelet/nodelet load depth_image_proc/point_cloud_xyz camera_nodelet_manager --no-bond image_rect:=depth/image_rect_raw points:=depth/points __name:=depth_points __log:=/home/martin/.ros/log/06ead13e-8337-11e3-a3f7-c860003ebb31/camera-depth_points-11.log].
log file: /home/martin/.ros/log/06ead13e-8337-11e3-a3f7-c860003ebb31/camera-depth_points-11*.log
[camera/points_xyzrgb_sw_registered-13] process has died [pid 7074, exit code 255, cmd /opt/ros/hydro/lib/nodelet/nodelet load depth_image_proc/point_cloud_xyzrgb camera_nodelet_manager --no-bond rgb/image_rect_color:=rgb/image_rect_color rgb/camera_info:=rgb/camera_info depth_registered/image_rect:=depth_registered/sw_registered/image_rect_raw depth_registered/points:=depth_registered/points __name:=points_xyzrgb_sw_registered __log:=/home/martin/.ros/log/06ead13e-8337-11e3-a3f7-c860003ebb31/camera-points_xyzrgb_sw_registered-13.log].
log file: /home/martin/.ros/log/06ead13e-8337-11e3-a3f7-c860003ebb31/camera-points_xyzrgb_sw_registered-13*.log
[camera/depth_registered_rectify_depth-14] process has died [pid 7090, exit code 255, cmd /opt/ros/hydro/lib/nodelet/nodelet load image_proc/rectify camera_nodelet_manager --no-bond image_mono:=depth_registered/image_raw image_rect:=depth_registered/hw_registered/image_rect_raw __name:=depth_registered_rectify_depth __log:=/home/martin/.ros/log/06ead13e-8337-11e3-a3f7-c860003ebb31/camera-depth_registered_rectify_depth-14.log].
log file: /home/martin/.ros/log/06ead13e-8337-11e3-a3f7-c860003ebb31/camera-depth_registered_rectify_depth-14*.log
[camera/points_xyzrgb_hw_registered-15] process has died [pid 7104, exit code 255, cmd /opt/ros/hydro/lib/nodelet/nodelet load depth_image_proc/point_cloud_xyzrgb camera_nodelet_manager --no-bond rgb/image_rect_color:=rgb/image_rect_color rgb/camera_info:=rgb/camera_info depth_registered/image_rect:=depth_registered/hw_registered/image_rect_raw depth_registered/points:=depth_registered/points __name:=points_xyzrgb_hw_registered __log:=/home/martin/.ros/log/06ead13e-8337-11e3-a3f7-c860003ebb31/camera-points_xyzrgb_hw_registered-15.log].
log file: /home/martin/.ros/log/06ead13e-8337-11e3-a3f7-c860003ebb31/camera-points_xyzrgb_hw_registered-15*.log
[camera/depth_rectify_depth-8] process has died [pid 6998, exit code 255, cmd /opt/ros/hydro/lib/nodelet/nodelet load image_proc/rectify camera_nodelet_manager --no-bond image_mono:=depth/image_raw image_rect:=depth/image_rect_raw __name:=depth_rectify_depth __log:=/home/martin/.ros/log/06ead13e-8337-11e3-a3f7-c860003ebb31/camera-depth_rectify_depth-8.log].
log file: /home/martin/.ros/log/06ead13e-8337-11e3-a3f7-c860003ebb31/camera-depth_rectify_depth-8*.log
[camera/depth_metric_rect-9] process has died [pid 7012, exit code 255, cmd /opt/ros/hydro/lib/nodelet/nodelet load depth_image_proc/convert_metric camera_nodelet_manager --no-bond image_raw:=depth/image_rect_raw image:=depth/image_rect __name:=depth_metric_rect __log:=/home/martin/.ros/log/06ead13e-8337-11e3-a3f7-c860003ebb31/camera-depth_metric_rect-9.log].
log file: /home/martin/.ros/log/06ead13e-8337-11e3-a3f7-c860003ebb31/camera- depth_metric_rect-9*.log
^C[camera_base_link3-22] killing on exit
[camera_base_link2-21] killing on exit
[camera_base_link1-20] killing on exit
[camera_base_link-19] killing on exit
[camera/disparity_registered_hw-18] killing on exit
[camera/disparity_registered_sw-17] killing on exit
[camera/disparity_depth-16] killing on exit
 [camera/debayer-4] killing on exit[camera/driver-3] killing on exit

[rosout-1] killing on exit
[master] killing on exit
shutting down processing monitor...
... shutting down processing monitor complete
done
```

Paradoxically, the only sensor that is working is the only sensor that I am not interested on using xD

So, to sum up:

- Microsoft Kinect:  **OK**
- PrimeSense RD1.08: **KO** (Device not found 'coz USB interface not supported)
- PrimeSense RD1.09: **KO** (Device not found 'coz USB interface not supported)
- ASUS Xtion Pro:    **KO** (Dies miserably)

I would like to add that the previous mix of Precise + Groovy was working properly. Any solution?

Thank you very much in advance!

**[UPDATE]**

After some researching it seems that the problem is the package ros-hydro-openni-camera, which currently is on version 1.9.2

The [proposed solution](https://github.com/ros-drivers/openni_camera/issues/18#issuecomment-24058663) is to download and install version 1.8.8

So, after doing it, the situation with *roslaunch openni_launch openni.launch* is as follows:

- Microsoft Kinect: **OK**
- PrimeSense RD1.08: **KO** (Same error as before)
- PrimeSense RD1.09: **KO** (Same error as before)
- ASUS Xtion Pro: **OK** (now it works, before it died miserably)

Good progress, but I would like to see the PrimeSense devices working...

**[UPDATE 2]**

I gave a try to the packages for OpenNI2:

```
sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-openni2-camera ros-hydro-openni2-launch
```

And get the following results:

- Microsoft Kinect: **KO** (No matching device found)
- PrimeSense RD1.08: **OK**
- PrimeSense RD1.08: **OK**
- ASUS Xtion Pro: **KO** (Device starts up, but Xtion Pro has no color camera, so it complains about not finding a calibration for /camera/depth/image_rect_raw and never publishes any point cloud)

Will we see the day when the universe lines up and all the devices JUST WORK? hehehe

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/121696/openni-not-working/) by [Martin Peris](https://answers.ros.org/users/1108/martin-peris/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5625 on 2014-01-23

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Athoesen](https://answers.ros.org/users/8296/athoesen/) on 2014-01-24**:
It could be because openni2_camera is explicitly made for this purpose.

http://wiki.ros.org/openni_camera

http://wiki.ros.org/openni2_camera

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For the newer Primesense sensors, you must use OpenNI2, OpenNI doesn't recognize them because the USB device ID has changed. The ROS version of OpenNI2 does *not* support the Kinect, and it probably doesn't support the Xtion Pro (it does support the Xtion Pro Live which has the color camera).

You can install openni/openni2 side by side, and use openni for Kinect and openni2 for newer primesense sensors. Given the question of future availability of either Kinect/Primesense, it is unlikely that anyone is going to put in the effort to integrate Kinect support with openni2.

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2014-01-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Martin Peris](https://answers.ros.org/users/1108/martin-peris/) on 2014-01-26**:
Thank you so much for your answer, what bugs me is that the PrimeSense sensors that I am using, were working perfectly fine before I upgraded to Groovy. If newer Primesense sensors must use OpenNI2, I believe you, but mine were working with OpenNI... but anyway... I'll just use OpenNI2